# Automatic method signature handling with Restlet?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, rest, restlet

I'm currently using Restlet as follows:

```
@Get
public List<Foo> retrieve() {
    if (getQuery().isEmpty()) { // if no args are given
        return Foo.getAll();
    }

            // pull out params manually
            float lat = getQuery().getFirstValue("lat");
            // ...
}
```

What I'd rather do is:

```
@Get
public List<Foo> retrieve() {
    return Foo.getAll();
}

@Get 
public List<Foo> retrieve(float lat) {
     // ...
}
```

Then if the query didn't match one of the method signatures, Restlet would automatically handle the error. Is there any way to do this?

(I'm using Google App Engine.)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, only the first cas is supported.

From an HTTP point of view, URIs are rather opaque and addition some special dispatching based on URI query encoding (HTML form way) has some pros and cons.